# Laravel Accessing JSON Post

Tags: php, jquery, json, laravel

I am struggling to post JSON data to Laravel. I have tried a number of ways to access the data in my controller, however, it returns []. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I would greatly appreciate any help!

`console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` output:

```
[{"ContactFirstName":"John","FamilyLastName":"Doe"}, {"ContactFirstName":"John","FamilyLastName":"Doe"}]
```

The AJAX Script:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
$.ajax({
            url: POST_URL,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        });
```

The Laravel Controller:

```
$json = Request::json()->all();

return $json;
```

It returns []. I have tried Input::all() too and had no luck.

Comment: You need serialize it again with laravel? not sure but i think data shouldnt be a string on the ajax `data: data,` or use `data: {jsonData: data} ,` then try to retrieve the value

Comment: you are sending something that doesn't have an identifier and seems to be an array [{}] not a object {}. try `data: {jsonData: data}` at laravel `Request::input('jsonData')`

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I have spent way too many hours trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$JSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
```